# Hibernate listeners + transaction info

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring Boot Data/JPA/Hibernate project I have configured following CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE listeners:

```
@Component
public class HibernateListenersConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private HibernateEntityListener listener;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerListeners() {
        final HibernateEntityManagerFactory hibernateEntityManagerFactory = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) this.entityManagerFactory;
        final SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl) hibernateEntityManagerFactory.getSessionFactory();
        final EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactoryImpl.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_INSERT).appendListener(listener);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_UPDATE).appendListener(listener);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_DELETE).appendListener(listener);
    }

}


@Component
public class HibernateEntityListener implements PostCommitInsertEventListener, PostCommitUpdateEventListener, PostCommitDeleteEventListener {

    @Override
    public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(EntityPersister persister) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
        //get transaction information(like ID) here
    }

...

}
```

In my listener methods like `onPostInsert`, `onPostUpdate` etc I need to get transaction information(like transaction ID).

How to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the transaction details kindly use the below code where in event could belong to `PostInsertEvent` or `PostUpdateEvent`

```
session = event.getPersister().getFactory().getCurrentSession();
Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
```

Transaction id is database specific.

With PostgreSQL, you could simply run this native query to get the current transaction id:

```
Number transactionId = (Number) session
   .createSQLQuery("select txid_current()")
   .uniqueResult();
```

For MySQL, you need to run 5.7 or later:

```
Number transactionId = (Number) session
   .createSQLQuery(
            "SELECT GTID " +
            "FROM events_transactions_current e " +
            "JOIN performance_schema.threads t ON e.THREAD_ID = t.THREAD_ID " +
            "WHERE t.PROCESSLIST_ID = CONNECTION_ID()")
   .uniqueResult();
```

or for MySQL 5.5:

```
Number transactionId = (Number) session
   .createSQLQuery(
            "SELECT trx_id " +
            "FROM information_schema.innodb_trx " +
            "WHERE trx_mysql_thread_id = CONNECTION_ID()")
   .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Thanks ! Is it possible to avoid extra query to database ? I need to get  some identifiers in order to organize all changes into revisions(from the same transaction)